# Is the sequence of words "modulus like parameter" meaningful?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, science, discourse-markers

Does the sequence of words "modulus like parameter" mean that the involved parameter can be considered as a modulus even though it can be something different in some cases ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"In this algorithm, P is a **modulus like parameter**." : Sounds ok, but written form is better like this : "In this algorithm, P is a **modulus-like parameter**."

While speaking, there will be no pause between "modulus" and "like", and that is indicated by the hyphen in written form.

Consider this case: Platypus resembles a **beaver-like** animal with a bill of a duck. Platypus is a **duck-like** animal.
Reference of this usage : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platypus#Taxonomy_and_etymology

Basically "A is B-like" means "A is like B, but is not B".

Comment: For how compose compound words in TeX/LaTeX: [Correct use of hyphen, en dash, or em dash in compound words](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46216/correct-use-of-hyphen-en-dash-or-em-dash-in-compound-words)